# Can't set bootstrap columns to flex full height inside my Angular component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

My [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-axm72b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.ts) is trying to set 2 bootstrap cols to full height of the component 'test' or the viewable window minus the navbar and div (isHidable) just below it.

The closest I can get is to use 'height: 100vh' on the col-6 divs, **BUT** this sets the col height to the entire window height including the navbar and div directly under it. It doesn't fill *just* the viewable component 'test'. So it ends up being scrollable, which is not what I want. I want it to fit and flex inside just the viewable component 'test.

So, I'm aware that if I didn't have the button underneath the navbar that toggled and hide, I could set the height to
some thing like

> height: calc(100vh - heightofnavbar)

But this doesn't work when you click the 'navbar', 'togglebutton' button, because the flexible height of the columns change.

Here is my component 'test' and my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-axm72b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.ts)

```html
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-6 flex-fill" style="background-color: green; ">
    scrollable list of items here
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 flex-fill" style="background-color: red; height: 100vh;">
    <div height="100%" width="100%">google map here</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For Yurzui's fix. Here is my app.component.html code

```html
<div class="page-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'toggled' : sidebarState}" (window:resize)="onResize()">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <div class="page-content">
    <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
    <app-alert></app-alert>
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
    <div class="overlay" (click)="toggleSidebar()" [ngClass]="{'show' : !sidebarState}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-q1cwqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html

Comment: it can't be scrollable...I mean if the content in the left column is long the left col can be scrollable but not the right col. The right column has to fit a map. additionaly, if there is no content in the left col, the whole map(screen) on the right has to be visible.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-q1cwqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: hi Yurzui, thanks for the update. Can you help me with where to place the css you created. I have a slighty more complex app.component.html file then the stackblitz. I'll post it above. I'm a little unfamiliar with :host, but after googling it I read that it applies to the parent tag?